# Checking if a function induces a measure, and if it does, calculating an explicit integral

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to calculate a lebesgue integral, or even finding if one exists. I am given the following function: $g(x)=\text{the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$}$

I must first show that it induces a measure, and I think it does since g is monotone increasing and right continuous. Is this true?

If it does induce a measure $\gamma$ (which I am pretty sure it does from my reasoning above), how can I calculate $\int_{[-11/2,13/2]}x^2d\gamma(x)$ ?

I am pretty sure the answer to this integral is just a number.

I am not familiar with how to explicitly calculate lebesgue integrals.

Comment: Hint: The greatest integer function is constant almost everywhere.

Comment: "Induces a measure" is a very vague phrase. What do you mean by that?

Comment: From what I've read, by lebesgue-stieltjis theory, g(x) induces a measure.

Comment: Split the integral in pieces. For example, the integral on an interval that doesn't contain an integer, will have $g$ constant. Therefore $\gamma$ is the zero measure there. Therefore, you integral is the same as $\int_{\{-5,-4,-3,...,6\}}x^2d\gamma=\sum_{k=-5}^{6}k^2\gamma(\{k\})$. Now we need to find the measure of each of those points. For $n$ integer, $\gamma(\{n\})=\lim_{x\to n^-}\gamma((x,n])=\lim_{x\to n^-}(g(n)-g(x))$. Observe that $g$ has a jump of length $1$ at each integer.

Comment: That makes sense to me, the function has measure 1 as it jumps from up from all numbers just smaller than -4 to -4, then all numbers just smaller than -3 to -3, and so on. The first jump it makes is from -6 to -5 though, correct (since 11/2 is less than -5, so the greatest integer less than -5.5 is -6)? In total, it seems to make 12 jumps in total of length 1. Does that mean the answer is 12?

Comment: No. The jump at an integer is $\lim_{x\to n^-}(g(n)-g(x))=1$, but that is just the measure $\gamma(\{n\})$. Your integral is the sum $\sum_{k=-5}^{6}k^2\gamma(\{n\})=\sum_{k=-5}^{6}k^2$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami That is not what [Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) is. Stieltjes would be $\int fdg$, and it is the same as integration with respect to the measure $\gamma(E)=m(g^{-1}(E))$.

Comment: Yes, so that clearly equals 25+16+9+4+1+1+4+9+16+25+36=146. That's right? And @MartinArgerami, if I do use "Lebesgue-Stieltijes" theory, does that make that answer incorrect?

Comment: @user547630 Yes. That would be the value of the integral. And no, both interpretations of what you mean by measure are the same.

Comment: @totoro: you are right, my bad.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, just one more question, why isn't the sum the following: $\sum_{k=-6}^6k^2$, since the function begins at -6. Or since the first jump is to -5, the integral is calculated from there?